# How can I set environment variables in my Javascript file rather than the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I'm writing a program that connects to Google Sheets API. In theory I could set the environment vars in the shell but that's not what I want to do. I have tried:

```
var authorizationDetails = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "myapp",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "myproj@myproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "yyyyy",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/myapp%40myapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT = 'myProject';
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = authorizationDetails;
```

and I get

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The file at [object Object] does not exist, or it is not a file. ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/mnt/c/Users/me/desktop/myfolder/myproj/myfolder/[object Object]'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1461:7)
    at GoogleAuth._getApplicationCredentialsFromFilePath
```

The environment var needs to be set before the main function. How can I set environment variables in the node.js script itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package dotenv will pull from a .env file in your project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

## dotenv

What you need to do is install a package called `dotenv` this allows you to create environment variables in its own dedicated file:

```sh
npm i dotenv
```

Link to package → https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

---

After you have installed it require the `dotenv` package as early as you can in your project like this:

```js
// Main.js
require('dotenv').config()
// code below
...
```

---

### .env file

Then in the root folder of your project (where your `package.json` is) create a file called `.env` then you can create environmental variables like this:

```
// .env
NEW_VAR="hello"
ANOTHER_ONE="DJ Khaled"
```

### Syntax of .env

just like declaring a variable in any code lang with `.env` it is no different `NAME=VALUE` the name of you env variable should be all upper case and use_snake_case, it is not needed just good practice.

Plus capitalisation in code looks cool ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) (ง ͠° ͟ل͜ ͡°)ง

---

Then you can use them how you would any environment variable:

```js
console.log(process.env.NEW_VAR)
```

---

### Bonus

If you would like to have your `.env` file somewhere other then the root folder you can do this when you include your `dotenv` package

```js
//Main.js
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + 'path/to/env/file/.env'})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're trying to assign an environmental variable to a Javascript object. It must be a string. As you can see from your error output, the Google API is able to see what you set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable to. Since your question is specifically how to do this from within JS and not externally, try this:

```
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/my/file/with/credentials.json";
```

I have edited my answer because [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS expects a file path](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) and not a JSON string. However, it is still true that you do not assign environmental variables to non-stringified JavaScript objects.